# string.chars.length vs string.length

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm migrating from Rails 2.1.2 to 2.3.5 and one of the items that doesn't work anymore is

```
"string".chars.length
```

I used the console to discover that "string".chars is a ActiveSupport method in 2.1.2 and an Enumerable in 2.3.5

So, in completing this migration, I was wondering what the difference is in using

```
"string".chars.length
```

vs

```
"string".length
```

Will they return the same thing? They appear to, I just wanted to know if you know the difference so I can learn?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you were using the `#chars` method because you were dealing with unicode strings, then you can use `#mb_chars` instead, and this is probably your best bet to guarantee your code acts the exact same as it did in 2.1.2:

```
"string".mb_chars.length
=> 6
```

However, if you're using Ruby 1.9, or if you're on Ruby 1.8 but don't need to deal with any unicode strings, you can just use `"string".length`. (In Ruby 1.9, `#mbchars` just returns `self` anyway since 1.9 has much better support for unicode strings.)

See [the API documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/String/Multibyte.html#M001039) for more info.